# Invertible functions and their properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

If an n × n matrix A is singular, then the columns of A must
be linearly independent. Is this true?

Invertible functions must be bijective

Invertible functions must have square matrices

Invertible functions must span R^n

Also, am I missing some other must conditions of invertible or singular functions?

What's special about invertible functions anyway?

Comment: On the contrary, singular matrices have columns that are linearly *dependent*. This can be used as the definition of a singular matrix. If singular matrices are defined in a different way in your course, you should probably state the definition that you're using as part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is singular, then the columns of $A$ must be linearly independent. Is this true?

No, it's exactly the opposite.

> Invertible functions must be bijective

Yes.

> Invertible functions must have square matrices

Invertible **linear** functions can be represented by square (nonsingular) matrices.

> Invertible functions must span $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Assuming that they are linear, and their codomain is $\mathbb{R}^n$, then yes.

> Also, am I missing some other must conditions of invertible or singular functions?

Determinant, eigenvalues,...

> What's special about invertible functions anyway?

They have inverse.